# Random Numbers in a Range of Cells

Tags: worksheet-function, vba, code, random-number-generator

I want to generate random numbers in my model. Every time I run the macro my cells range "G8:H34" have to fill in with different random numbers that should be integers from 0 to 2.

I have to generate those numbers in VBA, because I need to use them in order to optimize a model for a minimal costs and use loop after that to find the best combination that minimizes the cost.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. (0) What software are you running? Microsoft Office Excel? OpenOffice? LibreOffice? Lotus 123? Please [edit] your question and tag it with the relevant product. (1) Please phrase your question in the form of a question. Questions that have a question mark in them somewhere are better received than those that just read like a wish list. (2) We are not a script-writing service, and especially not a do-your-homework-for-you service. Please make an effort to solve your problem on your own. If you get stuck, come tell us what you’ve tried and where you’re having difficulties.

Comment: So you are allowed to use =rand() or =randbetween(x,y) instead of VBA?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need VBA for this. Just use [`RANDARRAY([rows], [columns], [min], [max], [whole_number])`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/randarray-function-21261e55-3bec-4885-86a6-8b0a47fd4d33)

In G8 put this

```
=RANDARRAY(27, 2, 0, 2, TRUE)
```

and random numbers will be filled in the range G8:H34 automatically

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Range("G8:H34")
    With r
        .Formula = "=randbetween(0,2)"
        .Copy
        .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    End With
End Sub
```